# How to configure displaying hidden folder or file on FMElfinderBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, elfinder

showhidden configuration on FMElfinderBundle did not work for me. I set this setting on config.yml like this:

```
fm_elfinder:
    locale: %locale% # defaults to current request locale
    editor: ckeditor # other choices are tinymce or simple
    showhidden: true # defaults to false
    fullscreen: false # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
```

Answer (score 0):

showhidden option was removed a time ago, i returned this option recently (check master branch), but moved it to 'roots' section, so it can be applied separately to each root.

Comment: could you please explain a bit more how to showing hidden file and how to config. I don't understand this part "but moved it to 'roots' section, so it can be applied separately to each root."

Comment: Well in your case, configuration for elfinder bundle would be like https://gist.github.com/helios-ag/1339da2425fb3f9b619b

Comment: I triple check but if when I set showhidden on uploads on config file symfony give me this error: "Unrecognized options "showhidden" under "fm_elfinder.connector.roots.uploads" and also I search in your bundle is there any handling for showhidden file in your code? I found nothing.

Comment: Check master branch of bundle (look at second last commit https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle/commit/43a6935747c12ffbe8a512c16881cdbae671c670)